# Python Data Frame: cumulative sum of column until condition is reached and return the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I am new in Python and am currently facing an issue I can't solve. I really hope you can help me out. English is not my native languge so I am sorry if I am not able to express myself properly.

Say I have a simple data frame with two columns:

```
index  Num_Albums  Num_authors
0      10          4
1      1           5
2      4           4
3      7           1000
4      1           44
5      3           8

Num_Abums_tot = sum(Num_Albums) = 30
```

I need to do a cumulative sum of the data in `Num_Albums` until a certain condition is reached. Register the index at which the condition is achieved and get the correspondent value from `Num_authors`.

Example:
cumulative sum of `Num_Albums` until the sum equals 50% ± 1/15 of 30 (--> 15±2):

```
10 = 15±2? No, then continue;
10+1 =15±2? No, then continue
10+1+41 = 15±2? Yes, stop.
```

Condition reached at index 2. Then get `Num_Authors` at that index: `Num_Authors(2)=4`

I would like to see if there's a function already implemented in `pandas`, before I start thinking how to do it with a while/for loop....

[I would like to specify the column from which I want to retrieve the value at the relevant index (this comes in handy when I have e.g. 4 columns and i want to sum elements in column 1, condition achieved =yes then get the correspondent value in column 2; then do the same with column 3 and 4)].

Answer (score 7):

***Opt - 1:***

You could compute the cumulative sum using [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html). Then use [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) with it's inbuilt tolerance parameter to check if the values  present in this series  lies within the specified threshold of 15 +/- 2. This returns a boolean array.

Through [`np.flatnonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html), return the ordinal values of the indices for which the `True` condition holds. We select the first instance of a `True` value.

Finally, use `.iloc` to retrieve value of the column name you require based on the index computed earlier.

```
val = np.flatnonzero(np.isclose(df.Num_Albums.cumsum().values, 15, atol=2))[0]
df['Num_authors'].iloc[val]      # for faster access, use .iat 
4
```

When performing `np.isclose` on the `series` later converted to an array:

```
np.isclose(df.Num_Albums.cumsum().values, 15, atol=2)
array([False, False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

***Opt - 2:***

Use [`pd.Index.get_loc`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) on the `cumsum` calculated series which also supports a `tolerance` parameter on the `nearest` method.

```
val = pd.Index(df.Num_Albums.cumsum()).get_loc(15, 'nearest', tolerance=2)
df.get_value(val, 'Num_authors')
4
```

***Opt - 3:***

Use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to find the first index of a `True` value for the boolean mask created after `sub` and `abs` operations on the `cumsum` series:

```
df.get_value(df.Num_Albums.cumsum().sub(15).abs().le(2).idxmax(), 'Num_authors')
4
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you can directly add a column with the cumulative sum as:

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   index  Num_Albums  Num_authors
0      0          10            4
1      1           1            5
2      2           4            4
3      3           7         1000
4      4           1           44
5      5           3            8

In [4]: df['cumsum'] = df['Num_Albums'].cumsum()

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   index  Num_Albums  Num_authors  cumsum
0      0          10            4      10
1      1           1            5      11
2      2           4            4      15
3      3           7         1000      22
4      4           1           44      23
5      5           3            8      26
```

And then apply the condition you want on the `cumsum` column. For instance you can use `where` to get the full row according to the filter. Setting the tolerance `tol`:

```
In [18]: tol = 2

In [19]: cond = df.where((df['cumsum']>=15-tol)&(df['cumsum']<=15+tol)).dropna()

In [20]: cond
Out[20]: 
   index  Num_Albums  Num_authors  cumsum
2    2.0         4.0          4.0    15.0
```

Comment: This is great! Now, say that I want to extract the values corresponding to conditions stored in an array (named ARRAY) and pass these values to a list (named: cond) or another array. In matlab syntax I'd do something like:                                                                                  for i in ARRAY:                                                                                                  cond[i] = df.where((df['cumsum'] >=ARRAY[i]-tol)&(...)).dropna()                   How do I do it in python? Would it be more appropriate to open another question?

Comment: Yes please, it's better to keep the style of one-post, one-question.

Comment: I did it, it is here if you want to look at it when you have time. I'd appreciate it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545936/python-iterate-over-a-data-frame-column-check-for-a-condition-value-stored-in

Answer (score 1):

This could even be done as following code:

```
def your_function(df):
     sum=0
     index=-1
     for i in df['Num_Albums'].tolist():
       sum+=i
       index+=1
       if sum == ( " your_condition " ):
              return (index,df.loc([df.Num_Albums==i,'Num_authors']))
```

This would actually return a tuple of your index and the corresponding value of Num_authors as soon as the "your condition" is reached.

or could even be returned as an array by

```
def your_function(df):
     sum=0
     index=-1
     for i in df['Num_Albums'].tolist():
       sum+=i
       index+=1
       if sum == ( " your_condition " ):
              return df.loc([df.Num_Albums==i,'Num_authors']).index.values
```

I am not able to figure out the condition you mentioned of the cumulative sum as when to stop summing so I mentioned it as " your_condition " in the code!!

I am also new so hope it helps !!